# $f,g$ are Riemann integrals, on $[a,b]$ which is increasingon $R$. prove if $\int_{[a,b]} |f|^pd\alpha=0$ then $\int_{[a,b]} fgd\alpha=0$

Tags: riemann-integration

$f,g \in {R}(\alpha)$ riemann integrals, on $[a,b]$ which is increasing in $\mathbb{R}$. prove if $\int_{[a,b]} |f|^pd\alpha$=0 then $\int_{[a,b]} fgd\alpha=0$.

my attempt:
since I can't assume f is continuous, and f and g are Riemann integrable I can write $|f|^p$ and $fg$ are Riemann integrable.

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}|f(t_i)|^p\Delta\alpha_i -\int^b_a |f|^pd\alpha|<\epsilon
\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i -\int^b_a fgd\alpha|<\epsilon_2  (1)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}|f(t_i)|^p\Delta\alpha_i -\int^b_a |f|^pd\alpha|<\epsilon_1
\end{equation}
since $\int^b_a |f|^pd\alpha=0$

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}|f(t_i)|^p\Delta\alpha_i|<\epsilon_1
\end{equation}

consider
\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i|=|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)\alpha_i^{1/p}g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i^{1/q}|
\end{equation}
where $1/p+1/q=1$.

with holders inequality

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)\alpha_i^{1/p}g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i^{1/q}| \leq \big(\sum^n_{i=1}|f(t_i)|^p\Delta\alpha_i\big)\big(\sum^n_{i=1}|g(t_i)|^q\Delta\alpha_i\big)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i| \leq \big(\sum^n_{i=1}|f(t_i)|^p\Delta\alpha_i\big)\big(\sum^n_{i=1}|g(t_i)|^q\Delta\alpha_i\big)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i| \leq \epsilon_1 \big(\sum^n_{i=1}|g(t_i)|^q\Delta\alpha_i\big)
\end{equation}

from above proved (1)

\begin{equation}
 |\int^b_a fgd\alpha|\leq|\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)g(t_i)\Delta\alpha_i|+\epsilon_2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 |\int^b_a fgd\alpha|\leq \epsilon_1 \big(\sum^n_{i=1}|g(t_i)|^q\Delta\alpha_i\big)+\epsilon_2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 |\int^b_a fgd\alpha|\leq \epsilon
\end{equation}

after this point, I'm not sure how I can go further, if you have any ideas appreciate your help.

note that $/int_a^b|f|^pd\alpha=0$ doesn't implies |f|=0 since its an rirmman integral

Comment: Who or what is increasing on $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: its $\alpha$. [a,b]  which is incresing on R

Comment: Why should the integral of $f$ affect that of $g$? No relation is stated between the two.

Comment: there is no relation between f and g except they are Riemann integrals